# How to exclude Runners from handling a job in .gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to figure out how to exclude runners from handling a job in Gitlab.

Currently we have 4 available Runners (lets call them **A, B, C, D**) available for building any project.

All of our apps have a `build` job that just compiles the project.  We don't specify a runner using the **tags:** field in the `build` job, so my understanding is that Gitlab will pick any random Runner that is available to the project to handle it.

For certain apps we don't want Runners **A nor B** from doing the build job.

Does anyone know how to exclude runners in the yml file?

Here's the build job for an app in the yml file.

```
build:
  image: nexus.ngidev.com:5000/system/jdk8
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
      - target/lib
```

I know I can specify a runner or runners to handle a job using the   **tags:** field.

But I only want 1 runner to handle the job, so I don't want to add:

```
  tags:
    - C
    - D
```

to the yml file as that would cause **C and D** to build the project.  I would still prefer to have Gitlab randomly pick an available Runner except for **A and B**.

**UPDATE for clarification:**
Runners **A and B** have tags/aliases assigned to them when they were setup so you can reference them explicitly in the yml files.

However Gitlab Runners **C and D** do not have tags/aliases assigned to them when they were setup.  So I can't reference them directly in the yml.

Thats why I was wondering if there's a way to exclude Runners in a yml.

Comment: C and D won't run simultaneously when you use the tag. GitLab will pick one out of them.

Comment: Understood.  But C and D Runners don't actually have any tags on it when they were set up.  So I don't think I can reference them in the yml.  So I'm wondering if there's a way to exclude runners from the build job.

Comment: Maybe try doing a backlist kind of thing. Have you tried to set something to let the job only run on runners that have no tag?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is not directly possible to define in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the current GitLab version 14.1 as of today ([tags definition in .gitlab-ci.yml](https://docs.gitlab.com/14.1/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#tags)).

I was having the same struggle, since I designed runners in different size with different CPU resources (`XS`, `S`, `M`, `L`, `XL`).

###### Possible workaround

Tag your runners by `<RUNNER_NAME>` and `not-<RUNNER>` tags and then use these `not-<RUNNER>` in the job definition to exclude runner from the job. The job will take a runner, that have all of these tags defined.

It is a tedious task to do by hand or change the configuration, so we use Ansible to automate it.

###### Example GitLab Runners configuration

Register with something like: `gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --tag-list "<TAG_LIST>" <OTHER OPTIONS>`

- Runner A tag-list: `A`, `not-B`, `not-C`, `not-D`, and your original other tags (e.g. `ruby`, `java`)
- Runner B tag-list: `not-A`, `B`, `not-C`, `not-D`, and your original other tags (e.g. `ruby`, `java`)
- Runner C tag-list: `not-A`, `not-B`, `C`, `not-D`, no other original tags
- Runner D tag-list: `not-A`, `not-B`, `not-C`, `D`, no other original tags

###### Example `.gitlab-ci.yml` job configuration

```
build:
  image: nexus.ngidev.com:5000/system/jdk8
  tags:
    - not-A
    - not-B
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
      - target/lib
```

This job will be now handled by either `C` or `D` runner, since only these two both have tags `not-A` and `not-B`.

###### Possible improvement in the future

The `tags` is imo missing keyword `exclude`, so we can do this directly in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`. I would expect, that it will be added in future versions of GitLab, but I was not able to see it in the GitLab issues as an open issue yet.